# Multiple Hosts for single bus in MassTransit

Tags: masstransit

Just realised that with V6 of MassTransit the support for multiple hosts in a single bus was removed. Is there maybe a different solution to implement it.

Our use case is to listen to the same queues on 2 different hosts. Consume messages and respond only using RespondAsync, my understanding is that it can resolve back to the originating default response queue automatically.

Thank You,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of MassTransit v6, there is no way to configure multiple hosts for a single bus instance.

In your situation, you should create two bus instances, one for each host, and configure the same consumers on each instance.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, do you think it will than be possible to use AddBus in AddMassTransit configure multiple time for each bus. Using .NET core DI or should i use AddMassTransit twice.

Comment: You can't call AddMassTransit twice. You can call it once, but you'll need to setup each bus instance in a separate hosted service. There really isn't a need to add the bus to the container, if you're just going to have a hosted service on each host.

Comment: Hi, Chris,
Is it supported in the latest MassTransit?
We are considering to place our app in cloud and it to aggreagate huge amount of RabbitMQ hosted in edge computer on customer site.

Comment: You can use [MultiBus](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/multibus.html) to configure multiple bus instances in the same container.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Thank you for replying. I looked at the page you suggested, it seems to add bus by hard code. However we are not sure how many hosts it would connect. I want to make my app connect dynamically. So I don't think it works for me.
I am wondering it would be better to manage multiple MassTransit instances outside DI container. Is the MultiBus way better in efficiency than the way I am considering?